# An ambiguity regarding Gauss law in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, dielectric

Gauss law states that the divergence of electric field is equal to the charge density ($\rho$) divided by $\epsilon_0$. And when we discuss electromagnetic waves, we say $\rho=0$ in free space. However, the use of $\epsilon_0$ in the statement of Gauss law itself implies free space, which would obviously force $\rho$ also to be zero. Then how come the textbooks still use $\epsilon_0$, NOT $\epsilon$, when Gauss law is introduced?

Answer (score 2):

Free space does not mean a space free of electric charge distribution. Free space means space that does not have material anywhere—it is "empty" or "devoid of matter". An example of a space which is NOT free space is a dielectric material.

There is a different equation for Gauss's law in dielectric media. This is treated in Griffiths' book in chapter 4.

Comment: I mean the relation gone over in Griffiths is still called Gauss' Law.

Comment: Oops. I conflated the argument that $\vec{D}$ is not on the same level as $\vec{E}$ with the naming of the equations. I have edited my answer to reflect your comment. @Triatticus

Comment: +1, but I'll add that it doesn't necessarily have to be a dielectric. The main point is that you are not in material media. For example, a magnetic material, or a conductor would not be free space, but they are not dielectrics either.

Answer (score -2):

Free space doesn't mean that space is void of matter but it doesn't have free charge as a source for field. The term free space is region devoid of source and minimum matter presence. If you have vacuum where there is no matter of any kind, then presence of unit charge produces same field as multiple of it.